# open form2 from form1 and hide form 1 and then close form 1 when I close form 2

Tags: c#, forms

Okay so I have 2 forms Form1 and Form2. 
Question: So I want to open Form2 when I click a button in Form1 and hide Form1 and after then I want to close Form1 when I close Form 2.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        f2.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }
}

    public Form2(string s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one. hope it will help :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        this.Hide();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();

    }
}

    public Form2(string s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = s;
    }
```

Comment: hmmm, now you can mark this question as answered @samjohal

Answer (score 0):

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(delegate(object s, FormClosedEventArgs e1) { this.Close(); });
this.Hide();
frm.Show();
```